# Change int array into string array based on its values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a nparray that contains 0 and 1 values

```
k = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0 ,1])
```

I want to transform the array into an array that contains `'blue'` if the value is 0 and `'red'` if the value is 1. I prefer to know the fastest way possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to index into a an array/list of `2` elements with those `k` values as indices, like so -

```
np.take(['blue','red'],k)
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: k = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0 ,1])

In [20]: np.take(['blue','red'],k)
Out[20]: 
array(['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

With the explicit indexing method -

```
In [23]: arr = np.array(['blue','red'])

In [24]: arr[k]
Out[24]: 
array(['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Or with initialization with one string and then assigning the other one -

```
In [41]: out = np.full(k.size, 'blue')

In [42]: out[k==1] = 'red'

In [43]: out
Out[43]: 
array(['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def app1(k):
    return np.take(['blue','red'],k)

def app2(k):
    arr = np.array(['blue','red'])
    return arr[k]

def app3(k):
    out = np.full(k.size, 'blue')
    out[k==1] = 'red'
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [46]: k = np.random.randint(0,2,(100000))

In [47]: %timeit app1(k)
    ...: %timeit app2(k)
    ...: %timeit app3(k)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 413 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 908 µs per loop
```